# Layer conv2d_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor / Keras / Cloudml / R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-ml

I am using the R interface to Keras version 2.14, and version 1.5 for Tensorflow.

When I run the following code at my local machine, it runs without any issues. When I run it on cloudml, I get the error message given below.

I have checked the forums, but with my limited knowledge of python, unable to translate the solutions given so far to R.

Thank you for your help.

Error message:

"Error: ValueError: Layer conv2d_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: . Full input: []. All inputs to the layer should be tensors. Detailed traceback: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 414, in **call** self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 285, in assert_input_compatibility str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer"

Here is the complete code:

```
original_dataset_dir <- "./train"

base_dir <- "./cats_and_dogs_small"

train_dir <- file.path(base_dir, "train")
validation_dir <- file.path(base_dir, "validation")
test_dir <- file.path(base_dir, "test")

train_cats_dir <- file.path(train_dir, "cats")

train_dogs_dir <- file.path(train_dir, "dogs")

validation_cats_dir <- file.path(validation_dir, "cats")

validation_dogs_dir <- file.path(validation_dir, "dogs")

test_cats_dir <- file.path(test_dir, "cats")

test_dogs_dir <- file.path(test_dir, "dogs")


cat("total training cat images:", length(list.files(train_cats_dir)), "\n")
cat("total training dog images:", length(list.files(train_dogs_dir)), "\n")
cat("total validation cat images:", length(list.files(validation_cats_dir)), "\n")
cat("total validation dog images:", length(list.files(validation_dogs_dir)), "\n")
cat("total test cat images:", length(list.files(test_cats_dir)), "\n")
cat("total test dog images:", length(list.files(test_dogs_dir)), "\n")
list.files(test_dogs_dir)

# now create the model
library(keras)

model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = c(3, 3), activation = "relu",
                input_shape = c(150, 150, 3)) %>% 
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>% 
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 64, kernel_size = c(3, 3), activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>% 
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 128, kernel_size = c(3, 3), activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>% 
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 128, kernel_size = c(3, 3), activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>% 
  layer_flatten() %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 512, activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

# look at the model
summary(model)

model %>% compile(
  loss = "binary_crossentropy",
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(lr = 1e-4),
  metrics = c("acc")
)

# All images will be rescaled by 1/255
train_datagen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1/255)
validation_datagen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1/255)

train_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
  # This is the target directory
  train_dir,
  # This is the data generator
  train_datagen,
  # All images will be resized to 150x150
  target_size = c(150, 150),
  batch_size = 20,
  # Since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels
  class_mode = "binary"
)

validation_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
  validation_dir,
  validation_datagen,
  target_size = c(150, 150),
  batch_size = 20,
  class_mode = "binary"
)

batch <- generator_next(train_generator)
str(batch)

history <- model %>% fit_generator(
  train_generator,
  steps_per_epoch = 100,
  epochs = 5,
  validation_data = validation_generator,
  validation_steps = 50
)
model %>% save_model_hdf5("cats_and_dogs_small_1.h5")

plot(history)


cml1.R
library(cloudml)
#gcloud_init()

cloudml_train("cats-and-dogs.R")
```

Comment: I ran my cloudml on a training example that is part of the initial example for cloudml and R ([link] https://github.com/rstudio/cloudml/blob/master/inst/examples/keras/mnist_mlp.R). Unfortunately, I get the same error, which is given below.  From my limited understanding, there is something different about how the data is being passed to the layers when I use cloudml, compared to running on the local machine. Any suggestions would be appreciated. 'ValueError: Layer dense_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor.  All inputs to the layer shouldbe tensors.'

Comment: I have now run the same cloudml jobs using a different local machine (Windows 10), and it runs successfully. I made no changes to the files. My previous job was submitted through a Mac. Not sure how a cloud-based task is being affected by a local machine, but at least I have output.

Comment: Hi Murali, could you please send your google cloud project number and cloud ml job ids to `cloudml-feedback@google.com`?